# Google Play Billing Unity plugin alternative

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm new to Unity IAP. When looking for a way to integrate Google Play IAP into a unity project, I found the ["Use the Google Play Billing Library with Unity" documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/unity) which states:

> The Google Play Billing Unity plugin will not be receiving updates moving forward. This means that the plugin will remain specific to Google Play Billing Library 3. Additionally, any apps that are updated after November 1, 2022 will no longer be able to use the plugin.

Does Google provide an alternative? Or should I just use [Unity's IAP integration](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityIAPGoogleConfiguration.html) directly instead?

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same text just now. I believe you are correct in your assumption that Unity IAP is the correct replacement for this, since according to their documentation [UnityIAPGooglePlay](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.purchasing@4.4/manual/UnityIAPGooglePlay.html) the current version of this plugin already uses Google Play Billing v4, which is the minimum required version starting Nov 1.